# How many columns we can add in a SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, column, sharepoint-standard

I have client, who has a SharePoint List with 360 columns(including default columns).

My questions are

1. How many column we can add in a SharePoint list?
2. If is there any limit, why didn't it throw any error at time of column addition?

The only reason client gave me for these many columns is, it helps them to get all data in export to excel.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a limit as in you can only have X number. There is a limit of 8000 bytes before row wrapping in SQL occurs. Each field has a different byte value associated with it. You can see them listed [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary).

Comment: That means, data will be get added in next row of SQL table after 8000 bytes. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Also does it will hit performance?

Comment: "Each time that a row is wrapped in SQL Server, an additional query load is put on the server when that item is queried because a SQL join must be included in the query. To prevent too much load, by default a maximum of six SQL Server rows are allowed for a SharePoint item. This limit leads to a particular limitation on the number of columns of each type that can be included in a SharePoint list. The following table describes the limits for each column type."